# Firestore get UID outside subscription

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

hy guys, I'm building an app with Firestore and angular but I ran into a little problem. I can't figure out how to store the users items in the designated document :  `doc(users/${user.uid}.collection('reminders')`.

I've tried a few solutions I found on StackOverflow and read the Firestore guidelines.

This is a sample of my code :

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, public auth: AuthService) {
  this.userID = this.auth.user.subscribe(user => {
  console.log(user.uid);
  return user.uid;
});

this.reminderCollection = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`.collection('reminders');
```

Could someone help me figure out how I can use the `user.uid` outside te scope and in the `doc(${user.uid})`

Comment: You have an error of parenthesis in `this.reminderCollection = this.afs.doc('users/${user.uid}'.collection('reminders');`. Should be `this.reminderCollection = this.afs.doc('users/${user.uid}').collection('reminders');`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it returns an error "Cannot find name 'user'". Would you happen to know how I can fix this error ?